# If |a - b| < |a - c|, then |1 - $\frac{a}{b}$| < |1 - $\frac{a}{c}$|?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, irrationality-measure

If |a - b| < |a - c|, then |1 - $\frac{a}{b}$| < |1 - $\frac{a}{c}$|

Is that true for all real values? If so, can someone point me to a proof?

(**EDIT:** I made a mistake in my context. When comparing "closeness", I should have put 'a' in the **denominator**. Then I'm pretty sure |a - b| < |a - c| implies |1 - $\frac{b}{a}$| < |1 - $\frac{c}{a}$|. However, I'm going to let the question remain, as it might be interesting to see what happens when a is put to the numerator.)

I used to think so but I may have come up with a counter-example. It's very confusing though so I want to first provide some background. Also, **I don't know all the official terminology** for these things, which is why the background might help.

The idea is how to measure the "closeness" of an approximation to some true value. There are two ways of doing it, absolute difference and relative ratio.

So if our true value is 2.5, and we want to test approximations of 2.25 and 2.75, we could say that 2.5 - 2.25 is 0.25 and 2.75 - 2.5 is also 0.25, so they are equally close.

But we could also try looking at the ratios. $\frac{2.5}{2.25}$ = 1.111..., and $\frac{2.5}{2.75}$ = 0.9090909... So this time, the second number is closer, when viewing it from the perspective of proportions.

Another concrete example. Our true value is 3, and our test values are 2.9 and 3.05. This time 3.05 is closer in both ways. In other words, the rule holds true:

|3 - 3.05| < |3 - 2.9|, then |1 - $\frac{3}{3.05}$| < |1 - $\frac{3}{2.9}$|

**It seems impossible to ever violate that rule.** If there is a smaller absolute distance between two numbers, then there should be a smaller percentage difference as well.

Now for my supposed counter-example.

a = $\sqrt{2}$, b = $\frac{7}{5}$, c = $\frac{10}{7}$

|a - b| = 0.014 213 562...

|a - c| = 0.014 357 866..., which implies b is closer.

|1 - $\frac{a}{b}$| = 0.010 152 545...

|1 - $\frac{a}{c}$| = 0.010 050 506..., which implies c is closer.

How is it possible? Does it have something to do with the coincidence that $\frac{b}{a}$ = $\frac{a}{c}$ due to square root "normalization"? By that I mean:

$\displaystyle \frac{\frac{7}{5}}{\sqrt{2}} * \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{7*\sqrt{2}}{5*2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\frac{10}{7}}$

If so I can't fathom how. I feel like I might be missing something obvious.

Btw if someone can clarify what the official terminology is, that would be a big help. I might be able to search and find answers on my own if I just knew the proper names of these things.

Comment: Take $ b = 0.1, a = 1, c = 2$. What do you get? Do you see how I created this?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I see it. I think I should've added, for all real numbers >= 1.

Comment: Take  $b  = 10, a = 100, c = 200$. What do you get? What's crucial about the setup, in order to get the counter example?

Comment: @CalvinLin I see. b < a but c > a. If they were both less than a, or both greater than a, i think it would work. But more importantly, I see a totally wrong setup in my context. When comparing "closeness", i should have absolutely put a in the denominator.

Comment: Right, the denominator is crucial (as indicated by my solution). For the new version, yes $|a-b| < |a-c| \Rightarrow | 1 - \frac{b}{a} | < | 1 - \frac{c}{a} |$ for $ a \neq 0$ because we're dividing throughout by $ |a| > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are given that $ | a - b | < |a - c|$, and are asking if

$$ \frac { | a - b | } { |b| } < \frac{ |a-c|} { |c| }. $$

An obvious place to start would be if $ |b| < |c|$, then this statement might not follow.

This suggests we should look for a counterexample where $|b| < |c|$, so take a really small $b$ and a really large $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=1$, $b=10^{-3}$, $c=2$

$$|1-10^{-3}|<|1-2|$$

but not

$$ |1-10^3|<|1-1/2|.$$

Comment: You are right. I should have added, all real numbers >= 1. Otherwise it's easy to see how things get "flipped". **Edit:** Actually, it's the fact that b and c are on different sides of a. If b > a and c > a, or if b < a and c < a, i think my original statement would work. However, I see now that my original setup was wrong. 'a' should have been in the denominator for the purposes of comparing closeness.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for the problem.  Glad that this example and the other answers helped.

Answer (score 0):

If $\left|c\right| \leq \left|b\right|$ we have

$$\frac1{\left|b\right|} \leq \frac1{\left|c\right|}$$

which can be combined with $\left|a - b\right| < \left|a - c\right|$ to derive $\left|1-\frac{a}{b}\right| < \left|1 - \frac{a}{c}\right|$